# AppCompatyActivity in android 6.0 (sdk 23) is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android

i recently updated every single available update in sdk manager , and im now using target sdk23 in my manifests , Since my activities were overriding FragmentActivity back in sdk21 and appearantly getActionbar() returns null in android 6.0 , im forced to use AppCompatActivity instead FragmentActivity , but when i am extending it like this

```
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;




public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static boolean visible = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Main Center Resumed");
    visible = true;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("Main Center Paused");
    visible = false;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}
```

}

i get this error :

```
 The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

i have updated every thing, added Support library v7-appcompat , am i missing some thing guys?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was adding both app-compat v-13 and v-7 to the application